# Why can't I request both identity scopes and other scopes at the same time?

Tags: slack, permissions, bot

I'm trying to create a Slack bot and I received the following error:

> Invalid permissions requested
>   Cannot request both identity scopes and other scopes at the same time

I think I understand the error. For the permission scopes, I requested some identity scopes along some read and write scopes. However, I don't get why I can't do this. Does anyone know?

Should I first request identity scopes permission and then the other ones? I don't want to interrupt my company's admins too much :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Identity scopes are for the ["Sign-in with Slack" OAuth process](https://api.slack.com/docs/sign-in-with-slack) only. Their only purpose is to facilitate authentication of Slack users in a 3rd party web app. It's not meant for requesting API scopes and tokens.

If you want a token with API scopes you need to run the ["Add Slack" OAuth process](https://api.slack.com/docs/slack-button), which basically installs your Slack app into a workspace with the requested scopes and provides you with API tokens.

Which one of those two processes you want to use depends on your use case.

Let's assume you have a 3rd party web site and want to provide Slack users some extra features which requires API access.

Then you would need both:

First your app needs to be installed to the workspace with "Add to Slack". This has to be done once only per workspace and you would store the token.

After the app is installed users can login to your web page with "Sign in with Slack" and you would use the tokens you stored during installation to access the API for that workspace.